# Create Namespace Code Refactoring using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to create code refactoring extension using Roslyn. What I want to do is refactor namespaces according to my default namespace. It succeed to find and replace the namespace when it is single word only but when my namespaces looks like that `kuku.riku.example` and I change my default namespace to `aaa` the result is `kuku.riku.aaa` instead of just `aaa`. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
    public sealed override async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync(CodeRefactoringContext context)
    {
        SyntaxNode node = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDec = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)node.ChildNodes()
                                                                                  .FirstOrDefault(syntaxNode => syntaxNode as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax != null);

        string defaultNamespace = GetDefaultNamespace(context.Document);

        if (defaultNamespace != namespaceDec.Name.ToString())
        {
            var action = CodeAction.Create("Adjust Namespaces", c => AdjustNamespacesAsync(context.Document, namespaceDec, defaultNamespace, context.CancellationToken));

            // Register this code action.
            context.RegisterRefactoring(action);
        }

    }

    private static async Task<Solution> AdjustNamespacesAsync(Document document, NamespaceDeclarationSyntax declerationSyntax, string newName, CancellationToken cancelationToken)
    {
        SemanticModel semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancelationToken);
        var fist = declerationSyntax.Span;
        INamespaceSymbol symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(declerationSyntax, cancelationToken);


        Solution origionalSolution = document.Project.Solution;
        OptionSet workspaceOptions = document.Project.Solution.Workspace.Options;



        return await Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(origionalSolution, symbol, newName, workspaceOptions, cancelationToken);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't supported yet, because adding a dot can create very complicated corner cases if the new identifier conflicts with a `using` in a nested block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RenameSymbolAsync` renames just the part of the namespace that you're passing in, as you're seeing. Supporting namespace renames that add or remove dots is something we've wanted to build, but just haven't yet.

Comment: Do you have an idea how can I do that with the current version? by the way I can add namespace with dots but I can't remove one...

Comment: The ability to add dots is more because we didn't block it, and might have bugs. Short of you adding code to support it to the core, dot removal just isn't supported.